# Filtering parent and children elements of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, search

I have a list of dictionaries and its elements has id and parent_id fields.

**Main purposes:**

- If the parent_id field of an element is defined, it should be returning the rest of elements except itself.
- If the parent_id field of element is not defined, it should be returning the rest of elements. In other words, its all child elements. Because it is parent element.

I'll be sharing my implementation below. But I need more concise and Pythonic way.

```
products = [
    {"id": 5, "counter": 10, "parent_id": None},
    {"id": 6, "counter": 10, "parent_id": 5},
    {"id": 7, "counter": 10, "parent_id": 5},
]

def get_by_id(product_id):
    product = list(filter(lambda p: p["id"] == product_id, products))
    return product[0] if product else False

def get_by_product(product):
    p = []
    for i in products:
        if product["parent_id"]:
            if i["id"] == product["parent_id"] or i["id"] != product["id"]:
                p.append(i)
        else:
            if i["parent_id"] == product["id"]:
                p.append(i)
    return p

p = get_by_id(7)
g = get_by_product(p)
print(g) # [{'id': 5, 'counter': 10, 'parent_id': None}, {'id': 6, 'counter': 10, 'parent_id': 5}]

p = get_by_id(5)
g = get_by_product(p)
print(g) # [{'id': 6, 'counter': 10, 'parent_id': 5}, {'id': 7, 'counter': 10, 'parent_id': 5}]
```

I have changed ridiculous if statements above like this:

```
def get_by_product(product):
    p = []
    for i in products:
        if product["parent_id"] and i["id"] == product["parent_id"] or i["id"] != product["id"] or i["parent_id"] == product["id"]:
            p.append(i)
    return p
```

Comment: How do you use these, because you could probably change the data to a dictionary for \$O(n)\$ creation, and \$O(1)\$ lookup, rather than \$O(n)\$ lookup.

Comment: It is not used in live environment. It was just a trivial code for practising. Open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If your actual program has the `products` list is a constant global variable, declare it as `PRODUCTS` (uppercase global constants)
2. Using `list(filter(lambda` can be removed by a simple comprehension. A list comprehension is the preferred method of iterating over lists [as per PEP-0202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/#id5)
3. Instead of returning `False` in `get_by_id`, return a `None`, as that is more user intuitive.

Check the following:

```
def get_by_id(product_id):
    """Return a product from the list with given id, or None if not found"""
    return next((p for p in PRODUCTS if p["id"] == product_id), None)
```

There is no extra list being created in-memory. The generator expression returns the first value (if any) or defaults to the `None`. Check docs for [the `next` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).

For the `get_by_product`, you can have 2 snippets. One will remove the given product from list if `product.parent_id` exists, and another will search for child products.

```
def get_by_product(product):
    if product["parent_id"] is not None:
        return [p for p in PRODUCTS if p != product]
    return [p for p in PRODUCTS if p['parent_id'] == product['id']]
```

Comment: Do you have any source which explains the speed of list comprehensions over filter function?

Comment: @vildhjarta https://stackoverflow.com/a/3013686/1190388

Comment: if you add another product tree you can see the bug. if the product is not None, it returns all dictionaries except itself.

Comment: You could simplify the `get_by_id` function, by using the `default` parameter to the `next()` function as specified [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next). `return next((p for p in PRODUCTS if p["id"] == product_id), None)` instead would be sufficient.

Comment: @Jatimir That is indeed better. Updated my code above. Thanks :)